# Emacs: Set background color for specific window

Tags: emacs, elisp, highlight, emacs24, pinning

Is it possible to set the background color of a specific emacs window?

I am using the "dedicated window" functionality to pin an emacs buffer to a frame. However, I also want that window to be recognizable as a dedicated window.

Currently I am using `buffer-face-mode` to set a buffer-specific default font with a slightly darker background color. However, this formatting also applies to windows viewing the same buffer, that are not dedicated  to the buffer. Being able to set the font on a per-window basis would remove that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Doing it for one specific window is not a feature Emacs supports right now.  OTOH you can do it for a specific frame, so if your window is inside a frame with a single window (as is often the case for dedicated windows), you can definitely set the background-color frame-paramter (and should be able to set it directly from `display-buffer-alist` or `special-display-regexps`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But can I then prevent that frame from displaying any other windows?

Comment: You could additionally make it unsplittable (search for `splittable` in the manual).

Comment: My guess is that you don't really care about preventing it from displaying any other windows, i.e., making it unsplittable.  My guess is that you just don't want it to display any other buffers, which also means that new windows will not be popped up in the frame (e.g., splitting it).  This is already taken care of by declaring it "special-display" --- IOW, not a problem.  If you really want to also prevent yourself from using `C-x 2` or whatever, then, yes, make it unsplittable.

Answer (score 1):

The method that worked for me in Emacs 25.1.1 was using the `face-remapping-alist` variable. When the buffer is initialized, modify the `:background` attribute of the `default` face to the color you want. E.g., I make the background color of my Treemacs buffer different than everything else by adding something like this to my `.emacs` file:

```
(defun treemacs-mode-handler()
  (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
       '((default :background "#303030"))))

(add-hook 'treemacs-mode-hook 'treemacs-mode-handler)
```

Comment: If you display this buffer in more than one window on the same frame or in a different frame, you will see that it is the *buffer* that is affected, not necessarily the *window*.  In addition, the Emacs manual suggests using the built-in function `face-remap-add-relative` to manage the variable `face-remapping-alist`.  [However, I also prefer to manage the `face-remapping-alist` directly without using `face-remap-add-relative`.  But, since others will be reading these threads, it is customary to always try to mention the Emacs way of doing things in addition to any chosen variation thereof.]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to specify the buffer as being "special-display". That does just what you want.

You can customize one or both of these options (variables):

- `special-display-regexps`
- `special-display-buffer-names`

That's the easy way.  Emacs likes to consider these options obsolete since release 24.3, and it recommends that you use the incredibly complicated option `display-buffer-alist` instead.

This is all I do, to have all buffers with names that start and end with `*` to be displayed in their own, dedicated frames:

```
(setq special-display-regexps '("[ ]?[*][^*]+[*]"))
```

To get special-display frames to have different properties (i.e., frame parameters), such as a different color background, customize option `special-display-frame-alist`.

This is essentially the definition I use:

```
(setq special-display-alist
      '((font . "-*-Lucida Console-normal-r-*-*-14-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1")
        (width . 80)
        (height . 14)
        (mouse-color . "Yellow")
        (cursor-color . "Yellow")
        (menu-bar-lines . 1)
        (foreground-color . "Black")
        (background-color . "LightSteelBlue")
        (top . 0)
        (left . 0)
        (unsplittable . t)
        (user-position . t)
        (vertical-scroll-bars . right)))
```

But I recommend that you use Customize to set the value of all such options.